# Selenium and chrome driver on Jenkins: Connection to localhost refused

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a job on Jenkins 2.35 using Selenium 3.0.1 and Chrome driver 2.25 with Xvfb on a Ubuntu server. Chrome version 55.0.2883.75.
The driver fails to initialize with the following error:

> initializeDriver(com.myproject.invoicestests.InvoicesTests)  Time elapsed: 13.128 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:1904 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'test.test.com', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-103-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Below the initialization of the driver:

```
public static WebDriver initChromeDriver() {

    WebDriver driver;

    String chromePath;

    if (OS.contains("Windows"))
        chromePath = "/var/lib/jenkins/drivers/chromedriver.exe";
    else
        chromePath = "/var/lib/jenkins/drivers/chromedriver";

    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("DISPLAY",":1");

    final ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingAnyFreePort()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File(chromePath))
            .withSilent(true)
            .withEnvironment(map)
            .build();
    try {
        service.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    return driver;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is selenium running? `ss -tpln` will show you processes running that are listening on TCP ports. Do you see something listening on port 1904?

Comment: Are you able to launch selenium manually on the slave? I don't use xvfb, but for my CI I have a dedicated system running selenium and I use RemoteWebDriver on my Jenkins slave to connect to it, which to me is easier to maintain.

Comment: @varlogtim while running the build I used the command to display the listening ports, but the one listed in the error message can't be found.